# JS - How to update DOM in realtime across multiple instances of the same web app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, ractivejs, real-time-updates

I am building a massive real-time collaboration web application. It is a Web IDE that has support for HTML, CSS & JS programming and a stage area  that would reflect the results a la JSFiddle, Plunker etc.

Now, the twist is that, it would support multi-user real-time collaboration, where people viewing the same instance of the web application would be able to write code together that would reflect across all the open instances. I have figured out the race conditions, session management *et al*

What I am having trouble with is

> how to reflect the typing and/or deleting along with caret positioning
>   across these multiple instances giving the illusion that when one
>   person is typing, he is actually typing on all the instances.

The other thing is that [RactiveJS](http://ractivejs.org) says that it

> updates only those parts of the page that are out of date. Tedious DOM
>   manipulation is a thing of the past.

Which is a very nice effect in their Demo. Imagine, you are on JSFiddle and you don't have to re-run every time. So, my question is, how do they do it? What is the concept behind it?

I don't want to use any library for this. I am pretty good in JS. I am having a hard time figuring out the algorithm.

Things I have considered:

1. Dirty Checking [but, its dirty right?]
2. Delta Differencing [but like [ReactJS](https://facebook.github.io/react/), it would have to update the entire application state every time]
3. Object.observe [the browser compatibility is not realistic yet]

So, if you have anything that can help me go in the right direction, I would be really thankful.

Comment: Real-time collaboration tools usually smell like *Operational Transformation* algorithms to me: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_transformation - You might also want to check ShareJS: http://sharejs.org/

Comment: I was actually thinking about Operational Transformation but didn't know about shareJS. Will check it out right away. Thanks.

Comment: I can't use Node. My stack is LAMP with a custom Websockets server built with Python. I was looking for a client side state/activity/observation capability. I checked shareJS but seems to be a lot of lag in their code editor demo. I would check out racer though. Thanks.

Comment: Added comments as an answer - second part might be of benefit to you as I imagine it would cause a bottleneck sooner than later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realtime-collaboration tools, that allow concurrent editing/manipulation of objects/texts etc, usually use a variant of the [Operational Transformation algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_transformation).

OT is *not* trivial to understand, much rather implement so I'd suggest you take a look at already-cooked libs for this such as:

- [ShareJS](http://sharejs.org/)
- [Racer for Node](https://github.com/derbyjs/racer)

OT works, in some very basic way, similar to GIT

---

As an update to what you posted in the comments.

You say you are using Python. You wouldn't rebuild your whole codebase, I guess, but keep in mind that real-time collaboration tools usually benefit *a lot* from using an event-driven server-side language.

Since you are using Python, you could check out the [Twisted Framework](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/)

Comment: I will explain the stack. There is a website. You login and go to the Web IDE. You can chat via the Web IDE. Now, the website back-end is built on LAMP. The Chat is handled by a Websocket Server in Python that has a REST API. There are sockJS libs in the web UI that connect to this Python Web Socket Server for chat and real-time updates. I was checking out shareJS. Do I have to use NodeJS as back-end for it?

Comment: It is built for use with NodeJS. Most of the libs out there would be built on top of it so your best guess is to do some research for OT algorithms in Python or make a decision if it's cost effective to you to rewrite your Python stuff into Node.js - If you haven't built too much stuff yet it's good to make a sound architectural decision from the beginning of it.

Comment: Or may be, intercept the shareJS events and handle it via the Python Websocket Server that I already have.

Comment: You can test and see if it fits your case - In either case event-driven languages usually fare much better under the scenario you described. Test and see if you are satisfied with Python before rewriting stuff. Try to abstract/design your system in such a way that it would be easy to switch backends for this functionality in case you want to make a switch later and you should be in the clear

Comment: you spoke my heart :)

Comment: Though the accepted answer solves my problem, yet, I just felt to go ahead with ot.js.